# How to place text at the top of the bounding box

Tags: javascript, html, css, bounding-box

I have a code to tag images , where I draw a bounding box over the image and enter the tagname in the text area. What i would like to do is to place the tagname over the bounding box.

I have attached the image of the tag window below:

[image]

In the image above, the bounding box and the tag are displayed . The tag that is entered in the text area must be placed over the bounding box. I am stuck in this part. I don't know how to proceed with this problem.

I have attached the code below:

```js
var render = document.querySelector('#tags');
var btnset = document.querySelector('#settag');
var tags = [];
var nameTag = document.querySelector('#name_tag');

var $kids = $('#tags');
var $selected = $kids.children();
if ($selected.length >= 1) {
  nameTag.remove();
}

btnset.addEventListener('click', () => {
      var areas = $('img#img01').selectAreas('areas');
      displayAreas(areas);
      var color = ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
      console.log(nameTag.value);
      render.innerHTML = `<div class="tag" style="border:solid 1px #${color};"><i class='fa fa-eye' aria-hidden='true'></i><i class='fa fa-trash-alt' aria-hidden='true'></i>${ nameTag.value}`
```

```css
.tags {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.dynamic_text {
  z-index: 9999;
  color: #f00;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  position: absolute;
}

.imagearea {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  float: left;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#img01 {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imagearea" class="imagearea">
  <div class='dynamic_text' style='display:none;'></div>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01" src="fashion.jpg">
</div>
<div class="text_container">
  <br>
  <div class="img_text"></div>
  <div class="input_tag">
    <span class="right_sec_text">Select a region from the picture</span>
    <div class="error"></div>
    <div class="tags" id="tags"></div>
    <div class="input_box">
      <input type="text" name="tags" id="name_tag" class="input_textbox">
      <button id="settag" class="btn_settag">Set Tag</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone Help me with this problem to place the text over the bounding box.

Comment: Can you put it in something like https://codesandbox.io/ so we can play with it? For instance, it is missing the Select Areas plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some Css I used to place text outside the bounding box. The trick in css is to use a negative margin-top value.

```
.cpSubBox{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin:15px;
    background-color: #122f2b;
}

.cpSubBox h4{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```